# Why does $w=u-h$ satisfy mean value property on any ball inside $B$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]

I am studying *converse of mean value theorem* from the book *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger. Here I find some difficulty. Here's this $:$

I know that if $u \in \Omega \subset_{\mathrm {domain}} \Bbb R^n$ then for any open ball $B \subset \subset \Omega$ $\exists$ a harmonic function $h$ such that $u=h$ on $\partial B$. From here how did the authors claim that the function $w:=u-h$ satisfies *mean value property* on any ball in $B$? (**See the second sentence of Theorem 2.7** ).

I cannot convince myself by this reasoning. Why does this happen? Would anybody please point it out?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is harmonic, it has the mean value property (and presumably the book proved this already). So the proof of this theorem is only of the MVP $\implies$ harmonic direction. So it assumes that $u$ has MVP. (And then it follows that $u-h$ also does since $h$ does.)

I agree that it's not very clear that this is what it's doing.

Comment: Oh! I have understood it now.I am so silly that I have failed to understand it. Many many thanks @Chappers for your kind cooperation.